# I get NoReverseMatch error when trying to pass data from a form to database in Django

Tags: python, django, render, reverse

I am new to Django and i wrote some code which is supposed to take some data from a form in orderr.html and pass it to the data base ( the app is called order)

orderr.html

```
<form action="{% url "order:createpost" %}" method="post">  **this is where i get the error**
    {% csrf_token %}
    First name: <input type="text" name="first_name"/><br/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name"/><br/>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

views.py

```
@require_POST
def createpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('first_name') and request.POST.get('last_name') and request.POST.get('address'):
            post = buyerData()
            post.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            post.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
            post.address = request.POST.get('address')
            post.save()

            return render(request, 'order/orderr.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'order/orderr.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from order import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'order'
urlpatterns = [
    path('order_page/', views.OrderPage, name='order_page'),
    path('order_page/', views.createpost, name='createpost'),


    ]
```

UPDATE : i just modified urlpatterns and now it works without the error, however, the database does not seem to populate. Can you please help?

Comment: Well, because you don't have a URL called "createpost".

Comment: Doesnt this "order:createpost" go to the function in view called createpost?

Comment: This might not matter, but your form tag has nested double-quotes.  Try using single-quotes around `'order:createpost'` so it doesn't conflict with the surrounding double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py`, there is no url named `createpost`. The name of the url is `order_page`.

So, change:

```
action="{% url 'order:createpost' %}"
```

To :

```
action="{% url 'order:order_page' %}"
```

Comment: But how is that going to get to my createpost view function that i want to use? I added    path('order_page/', views.createpost, name='createpost') to my urls and 
now i dont get the error anymore. However, my database does not seem to popullate whatsoever

Comment: In the url, you have mentioned "views.createpost", so it will be called, whenever you visit that url.

Comment: well yes, now with what i changed it works, but the database is empty..

Comment: First thing to check is whether the if condition evaluates to true or not. Are you providing first_name, last_name, and address?

Comment: Absolutely. I tried rendering a wrong html page for the 'else' case ( if the input was not correct) but i did not get any error, so i dont think the input is the problem..